# Python function reassigning external list values

Tags: python, list, function, variables, assign

Im having trouble reassigning values in a list using a function. I except the variable x to remain unchanged after running the function. However it is altered somehow.

**My code is:**

```
    x = [0,0,0]
    def test(j):
        j[0] = "K"
        return j

    print (x)
    t=test(x)
    print (t)
    print (x)
```

**My output is:**

```
[0, 0, 0]                                                                                  
['K', 0, 0]                                                                                
['K', 0, 0]
```

**My expected output is:**

```
[0, 0, 0]                                                                                  
['K', 0, 0]                                                                                
[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Lists are mutable.  Why do you expect `x` to be unchanged after you run a function that mutates it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually creating two lists. `t` just copies the reference to the list `x`. Hence you're reassigning the value in your original list. It sounds like you want a copy of the list and reassign values on the new list? If so, change this line:

`t=test(x.copy())`

Answer (score 1):

All parameters (arguments) in Python are passed by reference. It means if you change what a parameter refers to within a function, the change also reflects back in the calling function.

Comment: Not always... this article provides an introduction to, in which cases will a change in a function reflect back to the caller: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/

Comment: python do not pass arguments by value: all by reference. But you are right... also python has two types of objects: immutable and mutable

Comment: Does this apple only to lists? I tried the same with a single variable and it worked as I expected

Comment: also `sets, dicts and bytearrays`. Individual variables as `int, string, float, long, str, tuple` are immutable objects.